# inlining CSS or not ? (can I take decision based on the CSS size)

Tags: css, html, performance

I have a css like this.

```
body{background-color:#eee;margin:0,padding:0,...}div{...}a{...}a:hover{...}
```

It's nice and packed.
and it's inside an HTML page, like this:

```
<style>body{backgr...</style>
```

now, let's also assume that the stylesheet does not need to be applied to other pages (this could be the case if I am writing a single page app)

Should I put it in external file (so that it can be cached) or shall I just inline-it in my web page ?

**Can I make that decision based on the size of the CSS ? (e.g. if 200 chars or less then  inline; else in a css file)**

Comment: Never go for inline. If you have only one single page, then try to add new additional css file.

Comment: In a single-page app, you could theoretically have a build process that does the packing and copying for you, so you don't have the drawback of the single file during development. But yes, trying to change something in the resulting file will be as much fun as debugging minified JavaScript. ;)

But to offer my opinion: I'd sooner inline background images into the CSS and sprite images than inline the CSS - it's just _one_ more request.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz good point about about background images and so on... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, do not use inline-css, for these reasons:

1. The CSS can be cached, resulting in better performance.
2. It would be a headache later on, when you have really huge pages of tons of HTML markup, to locate every inline-CSS rule and fix it. If you have inline-styles, it makes it more difficult to revise the look of the site.
3. The HTML markup defines the *semantic* structure of the webpage, and its visual aspect must be dealt separately.

Use inline-css when:

1. You have to target the behaviour of a single element.
2. You want to deal with precedence (inline-css has the highest precedence)

If you have a CSS of about 200 chars, applying on a single page, why not make it in-document, i.e. within style tags:

```
<style>
    /*200 char CSS here*/
</style>
```

Comment: @Gauragan Tandon the <style> is in-document </style>  I will edit my query to make it more obvious

Comment: @Zo72 I think you need not go for either external CSS file, or for inline styling. The current situation (code in `<style>` tags) is perfectly ideal. Use external CSS files only when the CSS code is too big for `<style>` tags, like eric meyer's reset.css

Comment: @Gauragan Tandon. Thanks. So you are getting my point. So the question I asked when is "too big" ?  200 chars , 1000 chars ?

Comment: @Zo72 When your CSS is big enough to not fit completely within one screen shot, it's too big. (where screen is of normal size)

Comment: @Zo72 And with font-size normal.

Comment: @Garaugan Tandon. I get your joke. but seriously do you get my question ? is there a good rule to determine when to inline and when not to ? I have stumbled on this http://www.phpied.com/style-tag-to-inline-style-attrrib/ and the author says 2k.

Comment: @Zo72 Well, I did not intend to joke. Anyway, I wanted to say that you should go by your rough estimate and comfort level i.e. when you really begin to feel too much CSS code is there in your `<style>` tags and you get tired of find and replace and it looks a bit odd too. I checked on my visual studio some of my past HTMLs, and tried writing some CSS code, and by my guess 2.5k would be more than enough.

Answer (score 0):

Don't go inline, it will make your head hurt when you want to change your websites appearance later on. CSS files can and will be cached , and you can minify the CSS in your CSS file for your production environment if you want to.

Also, on bigger projects (actually on every project) it is better to keep it separated , because it would result in a lot of "code" in one file.

Answer (score -1):

If its a single page for sure (really sure) you can use inline. This reduces the latency

Comment: thanks the question is not so much about if I can use inline... it's more when to use it and when not...